# Terraform | Cyclic dependency in "apply" stage when using "depends_on" for module

Tags: module, terraform, cyclic-dependency

I'm struggling with cyclic dependency issue in `terraform apply` stage when using `depends_on` on a module.

The error I got in apply is:

`* Cycle: aws_appautoscaling_policy.queue_depth_based_scale_out_policy, module.my_module.aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition (destroy), aws_appautoscaling_policy.queue_depth_based_scale_in_policy`

The `plan` stage looked exactly fine and there are no errors in the `plan` stage.

I have tried to identify the cycle in graph using below command,

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles -module-depth=0 -type=plan  | dot -Tsvg > graph-plan.svg
```

There is no cycle shown in `plan` graph.
Then, tried to identify cycle in `apply` using,

```
terraform graph -draw-cycles -module-depth=0 -type=apply  | dot -Tsvg > graph-apply.svg
```

Sadly, this commands is unable to show cycle in graph.

Fortunately, I am able to see the cycle in `apply` stage graph using these below commands,

```
terraform plan -out tfplan
terraform graph -draw-cycles -module-depth=0 tfplan | dot -Tsvg > graph-apply.svg
```

The cycle in my graph looks like this,

[image: Graph showing cycle in apply stage]

Although, I am still unable to make out for the reason for this cycle in graph.

Moreover, it seems issue is specifically with adding `depends_on` on a module.
Since I already have few more `aws_appautoscaling_policy` in my module which do depends on `aws_appautoscaling_target` which depends on `aws_ecs_service` and hence eventually depends on `aws_ecs_task_definition` but `apply` for this works fine.

There are some `aws_appautoscaling_policy` which are specifically related to a particular app hence I am adding them separately (and not as part of module), but since auto scaling policy can only be added once service is registered as scalable target, hence I am adding `depends_on` on module, since `aws_appautoscaling_target` is defined in the module.

Here is my code snippet for module,

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                = "${var.service_name}"
  container_definitions = "${var.container_definitions}"
  task_role_arn         = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.arn}"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name                               = "${var.service_name}"
  cluster                            = "${data.aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.arn}"
  task_definition                    = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["desired_count"]
  }
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  max_capacity       = "${var.max_scalabe_capacity}"
  min_capacity       = "${var.min_scalabe_capacity}"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.ecs_cluster_name}/${aws_ecs_service.service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "cpu_based_scale_in_policy" {
  name               = "${var.service_name}-${var.env}-cpu-based-scale-in-policy"
  policy_type        = "StepScaling"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.ecs_cluster_name}/${var.service_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    cooldown                = "${var.scale_in_cooldown_period}"
    metric_aggregation_type = "Average"
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_upper_bound = "${var.scale_in_step_adjustment_upper_bound}"
      scaling_adjustment          = "${var.scale_in_step_adjustment_scaling_adjustment}"
    }
  }
  depends_on = ["aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target"]
}
```

And here is the usage of module,

```
module "my_module" {
  source = "GIT_URL_FOR_MODULE"
  VARIABLES_AS_NEEDED_BY_MODULE
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "queue_depth_based_scale_in_policy" {
  name               = "${local.service_name}-${local.env}-queue-scale-in-policy-new"
  policy_type        = "StepScaling"
  resource_id        = "service/${local.ecs_cluster_name}/${local.service_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    cooldown                = "${local.queue_scale_in_cooldown_period}"
    metric_aggregation_type = "Average"
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_upper_bound = "${local.queue_scale_in_step_adjustment_upper_bound}"
      scaling_adjustment          = "${local.queue_scale_in_step_adjustment_scaling_adjustment}"
    }
  }
  depends_on = ["module.my_module"]
}
```

Steps followed in pipeline are:

```
terraform get -update=true
terraform init
terraform taint -allow-missing -module=${MODULE_NAME} aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition
terraform plan -out tfplan -input=false
terraform apply -input=false tfplan
```

Would be happy to learn the reason behind this cycle?

Another point to highlight is that `terraform apply` is successful when we just `destroy` everything and recreate from scratch. The cycle is only observed when I `taint` my task-definition and have some updates in my scaling policies which are placed outside of module.

Note: In my pipeline, I do taint the previous task definition, to ensure services are started with new task definition instantaneously, otherwise task(s) will not be immediately rolled out with new task definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to get rid of cyclic dependency.
Here is the approach used,

Rather than having a dependency on the entire module, I have added output for `aws_appautoscaling_target` in the module.
And then I am just using this output in the scaling policy to ensure there is an implicit dependency created.

Here is the sample code,

Module

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family                = "${var.service_name}"
  container_definitions = "${var.container_definitions}"
  task_role_arn         = "${aws_iam_role.task_role.arn}"
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
  name                               = "${var.service_name}"
  cluster                            = "${data.aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster.arn}"
  task_definition                    = "${aws_ecs_task_definition.task_definition.arn}"
  deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 50
  deployment_maximum_percent         = 100
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["desired_count"]
  }
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_target" "ecs_target" {
  max_capacity       = "${var.max_scalabe_capacity}"
  min_capacity       = "${var.min_scalabe_capacity}"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.ecs_cluster_name}/${aws_ecs_service.service.name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "cpu_based_scale_in_policy" {
  name               = "${var.service_name}-${var.env}-cpu-based-scale-in-policy"
  policy_type        = "StepScaling"
  resource_id        = "service/${var.ecs_cluster_name}/${var.service_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    cooldown                = "${var.scale_in_cooldown_period}"
    metric_aggregation_type = "Average"
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_upper_bound = "${var.scale_in_step_adjustment_upper_bound}"
      scaling_adjustment          = "${var.scale_in_step_adjustment_scaling_adjustment}"
    }
  }
  depends_on = ["aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target"]
}
output "scalable_target_id" {
  value = "${aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_target.id}"
}
```

Note the output code block added inside the module.
And here is the usage of module, where output of module is consumed in scaling policy name.

```
module "my_module" {
  source = "GIT_URL_FOR_MODULE"
  VARIABLES_AS_NEEDED_BY_MODULE
}
resource "aws_appautoscaling_policy" "queue_depth_based_scale_in_policy" {
  name               = "${local.service_name}-${local.env}-queue-scale-in-policy-new-${module.my_module.scalable_target_id}"
  policy_type        = "StepScaling"
  resource_id        = "service/${local.ecs_cluster_name}/${local.service_name}"
  scalable_dimension = "ecs:service:DesiredCount"
  service_namespace  = "ecs"
  step_scaling_policy_configuration {
    adjustment_type         = "ChangeInCapacity"
    cooldown                = "${local.queue_scale_in_cooldown_period}"
    metric_aggregation_type = "Average"
    step_adjustment {
      metric_interval_upper_bound = "${local.queue_scale_in_step_adjustment_upper_bound}"
      scaling_adjustment          = "${local.queue_scale_in_step_adjustment_scaling_adjustment}"
    }
  }      
}
```

Although, I am still unable to figure out why the cycle was there in the first place.